# Various activities use same views from one layout - how to refactor?

Tags: android

I have six activities like this. I tried to make custom activity that hold ImageViews so I won't have to repeat myself in every activity. Should I leave it as it is or can I make it somehow be in one place and let it be used by everyone (like layout is - it's just one and works):

```
public class ActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Bind(R.id.iv1) ImageView iv1;
    @Bind(R.id.iv2) ImageView iv2;
    @Bind(R.id.iv3) ImageView iv3;
    @Bind(R.id.iv4) ImageView iv4;
    @Bind(R.id.iv5) ImageView iv5;
    @Bind(R.id.iv6) ImageView iv6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        iv1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c1));
        iv2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c2));
        iv3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c3));
        iv4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c4));
        iv5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c5));
        iv6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c6));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract activity `ImageryActivty` that needs to override some method like `getContentView` which provides a layout id:

```
public abstract class ImageryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Bind(R.id.iv1) ImageView iv1;
  @Bind(R.id.iv2) ImageView iv2;
  @Bind(R.id.iv3) ImageView iv3;
  @Bind(R.id.iv4) ImageView iv4;
  @Bind(R.id.iv5) ImageView iv5;
  @Bind(R.id.iv6) ImageView iv6;

  public abstract int getContentView();

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentView());
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    iv1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c1));
    iv2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c2));
    iv3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c3));
    iv4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c4));
    iv5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c5));
    iv6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c6));
  }   

}
```

And your child activities must inherit from this one:

```
public class ActivityOne extends ImageryActivity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public int getContentView() {
    return R.layout.activity_one;
  }

}
```

Of course this layout must contain all the ImageView's with the proper id's. For this I´d recommend you to create a reusable layout `imagery_layout` and include it in each of your child activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <include
    layout="@layout/imagery_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <!-- And here it comes the content for this particular activity in case there's one -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for - I could even go without `getContentView()` since I have the same layout in each activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one abstract BaseActivity activity that will have all the functionality common to those  activities and then you can just extend the other activities with it that needs to have that common functionality

or you can simply use one activity and maintained all the states in it using some sort of switch statements all depends on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with one Activity. You can pass arguments to Activities as Intent extras. Define some String constants in the Activity:

```
public static final String ARG_IN_IMAGE_ONE = "ActivityOne.ImageOne";
public static final String ARG_IN_IMAGE_TWO = "ActivityOne.ImageTwo";
...
```

Set your Drawable ids on creating the Intent:

```
intent.putIntExtra(ARG_IN_IMAGE_ONE, R.drawable.c1);
...
```

And read from the intent in onCreate:

```
iv1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getIntent().getIntExtra(ARG_IN_IMAGE_ONE)));
...
```

You can also optionally make a static builder which takes the 6 image ids and returns the Intent.